# qx.ui.table.Table hangs my browser

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I have a strange bug. I create a qx.ui.table.Table and if not all specified columns fit into window (horizontal scroll appear) my browsers (firefox 3.5.6 and chrome 5.0.344) hangs. If i just set width for window large (e.g. from 600px to 800px) - all works fine.

May be I'm doing something wrong? Or how can I fix/avoid this 'strange' behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know bug in qooxdoo. See http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3279 for details. We will (hopefully!) fix this issue in qooxdoo 1.0.2.

For this moment you have to set dimensions of the widget containing the table slightly larger than table.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! For me I replace a Table with TreeVirtual :)